# Python writing strings and integers to a txt file

Tags: python

I am making a small program that gets basic information of your system this works and outputs the information in a console but I would like it so that the output creates a folder in the C drive and creates a txt file in that folder containing all the information.

When I run the program it creates the folder and txt file but contains "None"

```py
def run_all_checks():
    montior_cpu_times()
    monitor_cpu_util()
    monitor_cpu_cores()
    monitor_cpu_freq()
    monitor_RAM_Usage()
    monitor_disk()
    monitor_disk_usage()
    monitor_network()


if not os.path.exists('C:\System Information Dump'):
    os.makedirs('C:\System Information Dump')

    save_path = 'C:\System Information Dump'
    file_name = "System Info Dump.txt"

    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, file_name)
    print(completeName)

    file1 = open(completeName, "a")
    file1.write (str(run_all_checks()))
    file1.close()

    #def file1():
     #return run_all_checks()
     #info = file1()
     #file = open("System Info Dump.txt","a")
     #file.write(str(info))
     #file.close()
     #file1()
```

The commented code is just an example of what I have tried as well but didnt work.

Comment: it doesn't look like `run_all_checks` is returning any values to be written. What are you expecting it to return?

Comment: @joshmeranda I want it to write all the output from the functions thats within run_all_checks to the text file, How would I get it to return the values?

Comment: *Doesn't work* does not tell us what went wrong. But `run_all_checks()` has no `return` statement, so it returns `None`. (Or it would, if it were indented properly: I'm guessing that you pasted it wrong.) Then your code converts that result to a string: `file1.write (str(run_all_checks()))`. So the program writes the 4 characters `None` to the file.

Comment: *I want it to write all the output from the functions*: if those functions are writing to the console, then wrapping calls to them in `run_all_checks()` won't change that. Consider revising them to return strings with the results of the checks, and do output (either to the console, or a file, or both) separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your run_all_checks doesn't return anything. If you are not sure how long the function list is. You can keep a list of functions and iterate over it and return its value or even just directly write the value onto the file.
Something like this:

```
def run_all_checks():
   return "testing"
def montior_cpu_times():
  return "FUNC 1"
def montior_cpu_util():
  return "FUNC 2"
def runtest2():
  return "FUNC3"

funcs = [montior_cpu_times(), montior_cpu_util(), runtest2(), run_all_checks()]

for func in funcs:
  print(func)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `run_all_checks()` doesn't return anything. So that's why the text file is empty.

For example, try:

```py
def run_all_checks():
    montior_cpu_times()
    monitor_cpu_util()
    monitor_cpu_cores()
    monitor_cpu_freq()
    monitor_RAM_Usage()
    monitor_disk()
    monitor_disk_usage()
    monitor_network()
    return "Checks ran successfully!"
```